# How to pass command line arguments to Mix Release built

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix

I am trying to pass command-line arguments to my elixir release. I have built the release using

```
MIX_ENV=prod mix release
```

Now, Am not able to pass any command-line arguments with the start command.

`_build/prod/rel/prod/bin/prod start arg1 arg2`

Using `eval` i have achieved passing the arguments but it stops after a while.

`_build/prod/rel/prod/bin/prod eval "Hello.nodes([3, :node1])"`

Is there any way that I can pass the args through the start flag?

Answer (score 0):

> Using eval i have achieved passing the arguments but it stops after a
> while.
>
> _build/prod/rel/prod/bin/prod eval "Hello.nodes([3, :node1])"

From the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.12/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-one-off-commands-eval-and-rpc):

> The eval command starts its own instance of the VM but without
> starting any of the applications in the release and without starting
> distribution. For example, if you need to do some prep work before
> running the actual system, like migrating your database, eval can be a
> good fit. Just keep in mind any application you may use during eval
> has to be explicitly loaded and/or started.

I'm guessing that your `eval` tries to use an application that you didn't explicitly load before executing the eval.

> Is there any way that I can pass the args through the start flag?

It's not documented, but there are various ways to configure a release:

https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/config-and-releases.html

Maybe an `escript` would be a better fit?

> escript provides support for running short Erlang programs without
> having to compile them first, and an easy way to retrieve the
> command-line arguments.
>
> It is possible to bundle escript(s) with an Erlang runtime system to make it self-sufficient and relocatable.

Comment: I agree `escript` is the way to go but i am using distillery and `edeliver`, which can compile and execute the application on remote hosts. I will stick to it as it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: @OwaisQayum, Are you aware that mix itself can now create releases, and that a file named config/runtime.exs can be used to read environment variables at runtime(elixir 1.11+), then set application variables, which can be looked up by your code?  So, instead of passing command line arguments, you would set environment variables: `MY_INPUT=hello _build/prod/rel/prod/bin/prod start`